# Two different columns need criteria with SUM condition

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with two columns in a mysql database.

For example: Item_name, qty in table1

I need to retrieve all items by Item_name where sum(qty) <> 0

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
select item_name from table1 where SUM(QTY) <> 0 group by item_name
```

Thank you.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to add a condition on an aggregate, `HAVING` is used rather than `WHERE`:

```
SELECT item_name 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY item_name 
HAVING SUM(QTY) <> 0
```